# multivariate Gaussian distribution with identity covariance

Tags: plotting, graphics, probability-or-statistics, machine-learning

I want to draw Geometry (or contours) for multivariate Gaussian distribution with identity covariance matrix (or draw decision boundary). How this is possible via Wolfram's online at [Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/)?

Please provide me a short example or hint.

Comment: Without normalization you simply write: Plot[Exp[-(x^2+y^2)]]. With a covariance matrix you would write:Plot[ Exp[-{x,y}.mat.{x,y}]]

Comment: You need to give values to the matrix mat. E.g. for the identity matrix: ;Plot[Exp[-{x,y}.IdentityMatrix[2].{x,y}]]

Comment: Do you want your contours labeled as probability density values or by area or volume contained within the contour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Wolfram alpha you would enter:
Plot[Exp[-{x,y}.{{1,0.1},{0.1,1}}.{x,y}]]
[image]